# How to create Charts on Google Spreadsheet using C#?

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

After struggling, I've finally created C# program able to Read, Add, Update and Delete cells from/to a Google Spreadsheet. Now I want to create a Chart from data I've there, but I'm not able to do it.

I've done a lot of research around this. I found this [library repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.cs) with all things (I think) it's needed to do this, and I found a couple of examples using python and javascript, but for some reason I'm not able to put it together for C#.

Have anyone done that?

Comment: Why the downvote? Could you provide some feedback or ask for clarifications?

Comment: Can you please provide the code you have tried and explain what is not working? There is information on how to create charts [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts), this needs to be sent as the body of a batchUpdate.

Comment: I haven't put together any code for charts yet, otherwise I would have attached it. Just read and got familiar with possible methods, but as I said I didn't run any because I literally don't know/can't understand the structure of how to do it.

Comment: Well it depends on what kind of chart you want to make, what data you're using etc. I can give you a basic run-down on how to build the request body and make the requests to the API but it really depends on what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I just wanted exactly that, the basic run-down and I can take it from there. I was just blank, couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*In order to create a chart and add it to a Google Sheet, a `batchUpdate` request needs to be made to the API containing the Chart information.*

#### Run-down:

The first thing you need to do is build your request body, specifying all the relevant parts of the chart that you need. This includes the type of chart (column chart or pie chart), the axes, data sources, position of chart, etc. Full information for this can be found in the [Charts reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts).

Once the request object has been built, then a `batchUpdate` request can be made to the API by constructing a `BatchUpdateRequest` containing all the information previously constructed.

#### Building the Request:

The Request is a List object which you need to build before adding to a `BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest` object:

```c#
var addChartRequest = new AddChartRequest();
addChartRequest.ChartData = // Your data
addChartRequest.ChartSourceRange = // Your range
addChartRequest.ChartSpec = // Your spec
// I have included the Class References for all these below, check them out
// and add the structure you need

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest chartRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
chartRequest.Requests = new List<Request>();
chartRequest.Requests.Add(new Request
{
  // Build your List Request here following the structure for column or pie charts
});
```

The [column request structure](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#add_a_column_chart) and [pie chart request structure](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#add_a_pie_chart) are similar but require slightly differenct parameters.

#### Making the API call:

After you have built the request itself, the `batchUpdate` method needs to be called:

```c#
var ssID = "<your-spreadsheet-id>"
var batchUpdateReq = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(chartRequest, ssID)
batchUpdateRequest.Execute();
```

#### References:

- [Google Sheets API v4 Charts Recipe Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts):
- [Chart source data](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#chart_source_data)
- [Column Charts](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#add_a_column_chart)
- [Pie Charts](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#add_a_pie_chart)
- [Spreadsheets Charts REST Resource Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts)
- [Google API .NET Client on GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.cs)
- [.NET Quickstart for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet)
- [Google Sheets API v4 request body Documentation for `batchUpdate` method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request)
- [.NET: Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Sheets_1_1v4_1_1SpreadsheetsResource_1_1BatchUpdateRequest.html):
- [Sheet Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Sheets_1_1v4_1_1Data_1_1Sheet.html)
- [ChartData Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Sheets_1_1v4_1_1Data_1_1ChartData.html)
- [ChartSourceRange Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Sheets_1_1v4_1_1Data_1_1ChartSourceRange.html)
- [ChartSpec Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Sheets_1_1v4_1_1Data_1_1ChartSpec.html)
- [BasicChartSpec Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Sheets_1_1v4_1_1Data_1_1BasicChartSpec.html)

Comment: That's exactly what I was needing. Thank you very much mate.
I've entirely based on what you have done, and this is how I implemented this example (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#add_a_column_chart) you shared:
https://repl.it/@rodrigo741/GoogleSheetAPICInsertCharts. Hope it helps others as you've helped me. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I follow those simple steps to create a simple column chart inside an existing google spreadsheet.

1. **Get sheet id**

```cs
var sheetId = GetSheetId(service, spreadsheetId, googleSheetParameters.SheetName);
```

2. **Create basic chart axis lists**

```cs
IList<BasicChartAxis> basicChartAxes = new List<BasicChartAxis>();
basicChartAxes.Add(
    new BasicChartAxis()
    {
        Position = "BOTTOM_AXIS",
        Title = xName

    });
basicChartAxes.Add(
    new BasicChartAxis()
    {
        Position = "LEFT_AXIS",
        Title = yName

    });
```

3. **Create grid ranges for x and y axies**(for example:first 10 rows)

```cs
//B1-B10
IList<GridRange> yRanges = new List<GridRange>();
yRanges.Add(
    new GridRange()
    {
        SheetId = sheetId,
        StartRowIndex = 0,
        EndRowIndex = 9,
        StartColumnIndex = 1,
        EndColumnIndex = 2
    });

//A1-A10
IList<GridRange> xRanges = new List<GridRange>();
xRanges.Add(
    new GridRange()
    {
        SheetId = sheetId,
        StartRowIndex = 0,
        EndRowIndex = 9,
        StartColumnIndex = 0,
        EndColumnIndex = 1
    });
```

4. **Create series and domains**

```cs
IList<BasicChartSeries> basicChartSeries = new List<BasicChartSeries>();
basicChartSeries.Add(new BasicChartSeries()
{

    Series = new ChartData()
    {
        SourceRange = new ChartSourceRange()
        {
            Sources = yRanges
        }
    },

    TargetAxis = "LEFT_AXIS"
});

IList<BasicChartDomain> basicChartDomains = new List<BasicChartDomain>();
basicChartDomains.Add(new BasicChartDomain()
{
    Domain = new ChartData()
    {
        SourceRange = new ChartSourceRange()
        {
            Sources = xRanges
        }
    }
});
```

5. **Create the ChartSpec**

```cs
var chartSpec = new ChartSpec()
{
    Title = googleSheetParameters.SheetName,
    BasicChart = new BasicChartSpec()
    {
        ChartType = "COLUMN",
        LegendPosition = "BOTTOM_LEGEND",
        Axis = basicChartAxes,
        Domains = basicChartDomains,
        Series = basicChartSeries,
        HeaderCount = 1
    }
};
```

6. **Create and finalize chart request**

```cs
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest chartRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();

var addChartRequest = new AddChartRequest
{
    Chart = new EmbeddedChart()
    {
        Position = new EmbeddedObjectPosition()
        {
            //if you use an existing Sheet inside Spredsheet
            OverlayPosition = new OverlayPosition
            {
                //set position inside existing sheet
                AnchorCell = new GridCoordinate()
                {
                    SheetId = sheetId,
                    ColumnIndex = 2,
                    RowIndex = 0
                }
            }
        },
        Spec = chartSpec
    }
};

chartRequest.Requests = new List<Request>();
chartRequest.Requests.Add(new Request() { AddChart = addChartRequest });

var batchUpdateReq = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(chartRequest, spreadsheetId).Execute();
```