# Can I use direct JSON request in Google Sheets .NET API to create charts instead of C# .NET objects?

Tags: c#, json, .net, google-sheets-api

I got to know how to create charts requests in google sheets API using recursive objects in C# .net from [ChrisP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12939476/chrisp) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63900779/1740113).  It looks overwhelming to me to create so many objects recursively and I keep missing some or other objects.

Usage of JSON objects in python to create charts looks fairly simpler as shown in [google sheets API docs here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts?hl=en) Does G-Sheets .NET libraries accept JSON objects as below? Switching to python is difficult at this stage of development, so I still want to code in C# anyways.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "addChart": {
        "chart": {
          "spec": {
            "title": "Model Q1 Sales",
            "basicChart": {
              "chartType": "COLUMN",
              "legendPosition": "BOTTOM_LEGEND",
              "axis": [
                {
                  "position": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                  "title": "Model Numbers"
                },
                {
                  "position": "LEFT_AXIS",
                  "title": "Sales"
                }
              ],
              "domains": [
                {
                  "domain": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": sourceSheetId,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 7,
                          "startColumnIndex": 0,
                          "endColumnIndex": 1
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "series": [
                {
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": sourceSheetId,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 7,
                          "startColumnIndex": 1,
                          "endColumnIndex": 2
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS"
                },
                {
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": sourceSheetId,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 7,
                          "startColumnIndex": 2,
                          "endColumnIndex": 3
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS"
                },
                {
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": sourceSheetId,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 7,
                          "startColumnIndex": 3,
                          "endColumnIndex": 4
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS"
                }
              ],
              "headerCount": 1
            }
          },
          "position": {
            "newSheet": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately what you want cannot be achieved as if you plan on using Sheets API with C# .NET you will have to make use of the C# objects.**

As a workaround, you can always choose another technology for achieving your task.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking about at the moment.  Looking for python instead of C#.